# NDSolve point animation not working

Tags: plotting, graphics, differential-equations, animation, event-detection

The below code plots the path of a ball bouncing but loses 90% of its velocity each time it bounces. (adapted from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html).

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0,
WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.9 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Point[{0, y[t] /. sol}], PlotRange -> {{-.1, .1}, {5.1, -.1}}],
 {t, 0, 10}]
```

The `plot` function works as expected,

[image: ball bouncing]

however, the `manipulate` function, which shows a point that bounces like the ball should, does not. It returns an error

`Coordinate {0, {5.}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.`

What am i doing wrong with this code?

Comment: As the error shows, the argument for your points should not be in the form of` {x, {y}}` but `{x,y}`. One way to solve this would be to use [[1]]: `Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Point[{0, y[t] /. sol[[1]]}], PlotRange -> {{-.1, .1}, {5.1, -.1}}],
 {t, 0, 10}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comment. The `sol` yields `{y[t]->...}`. This argument will be evaluated in `Plot` but not with `Point`. If the aim is just to see bounce on vertical line you just have to take first part of `sol` (e.g `First[sol]`. If you want to plot y v time he is one of many ways:

```
sol = y[t] /. 
   First@NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5, y'[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.9 y'[t]]}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
f[p_] := Plot[sol, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{p, (sol /. t -> p)}]}, 
   Frame -> True, Background -> Black];
Animate[f[p], {p, 0, 10}]
```

[image]